# Using yearly data to predict quarterly data

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I'm wondering whether it's a valid approach to construct a model that uses a panel of company data that is available with yearly frequency to predict outcome data that is available at a quarterly frequency.

I guess our setup in this case would be to repeat the yearly data for each of the following 4 quarters (in which outcomes differ, but the yearly data then stays fixed). For this setup, I believe I will need to control for clustering of standard errors in each year along with the regular clustering of standard errors within each firm.

So, is this valid or is it advisable to also use yearly data as the outcome variable? I've tried looking around but most questions go the other way, i.e. having higher frequency data being the explanatory variable for lower frequency outcomes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some comments:

- I don't see any inherent problem with using left hand side variables on the quarterly level with right hand side variables at the annual level as long as you properly understand what error-terms may be correlated (as you appear to do).

  - As you recognize, cut and pasting your data 12x (eg. to get monthly frequency) doesn't give you 12x the independent observations or in fact any additional power.
- If all your data on the right hand side is annualized and there are 4 quarters for every firm-year etc..., then you should find there are some near equivalences between working at the quarterly level and the annual level if you do your standard-errors right.

  - It can actually be a fun exercise to see that two ways of formulating an estimation problem are actually equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try to look into both quarterly and yearly LHS data, it will serve as a nice robustness test for my thesis.